# Плавное изменение размера окна

Tags: c++, графика, sfml, окно

Для обработки изменения размера окна в sfml есть Resized, но если перетаскивать границы окна мышкой, то на время от нажатия ЛКМ до ее отпускания приложение стопится и соответственно новый кусок окна который был открыт черный. Причем такое происходит и без Resized, но с Resized просто получается узнать размеры. Как сделать чтобы программа не останавливалась от начала и до конца изменения размеров окна.

Comment: Полагаю, что никак. Эта неприятная особенность характерна не только для sfml.

Comment: @user7860670 очень жалко